# Perguntas sobre benchmark

Tags: debate, razões-fechamento

Uma vez um filosofo disse: "Perguntas sinceras, merecem respostas sinceras".

Acredito que o **stackoverflow** padeça de falta de educação.

Benchmark de APIs são consideradas `off-topic`?

Se são como fazer uma pergunta assim?

Fiz essa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/61200/api-de-pagamentos) sobre benchmark de APIs de billing em determinados casos, e ela foi logo fechada, sem nem ao menos dar a oportunidade de saber como fazer a pergunta corretamente.

Estranhamente o usuário que primeiro manifestou que a pergunta estava descontextualizada, já respondeu uma pergunta bastante similar. [Sobre benchmark de ferramentas para desenvolvimento.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8315/diferen%C3%A7as-entre-git-svn-e-cvs/8322#8322)

Não seria hoje em dia, pergunta sobre benchmark de API e benchmark de Ferramentas de desenvolvimento de igual importância?

No fundo, a escolha de uma API é uma atividade técnica de suma importância em um projeto de TI, e acredito que o **stackoverflow** deveria ser o local para essas perguntas. Estou certo?

Comment: Ótima pergunta! Estou ansioso para ver as respostas. Enquanto isso fica aí o link de uma discussão relacionada: [Baseado em opinião está sendo usada corretamente?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2071/3117). Esse debate do link me veio a cabeça imediatamente ao ler a palavra `melhor` na sua pergunta :)

Comment: Minha pergunta não tem a palavra `melhor`... hehehehe Então, há alguma "vantagem" para se fechar uma pergunta? Porque até no stackoverflow em Inglês vejo essa pressa de alguns usuários em fechar perguntas. Isso de deve a uma razão higienista? Ou simplesmente é uma carência do usuário de demonstrar atividade no stackoverflow? Porque cada pergunta séria fechada, é provavelmente uma pergunta não respondida.

Comment: Me referia a sua pergunta original, e não a essa aqui do meta. Olha o "melhor" nela: `Qual é a melhor API de pagamentos para um pagamento recorrente e sem preço fixo?` ;-)

Comment: Ah, na minha outra pergunta! Desculpa, esqueci de ver a minha própria citação.

Comment: Relacionada que deve ser fechada em breve: [Melhor Servidor Linux](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/61357/3117)

Comment: É que ele não especificou quais os parâmetros pra definir o "melhor". Porque melhor é subjetivo, mas se você definir os parâmetros não. Como: qual a melhor linguagem pra fazer uma aplicação que rodará em varias plataformas? Você pode responder objetivamente que é java.

Answer (score 2):

## Educação

> Acredito que o stackoverflow padeça de falta de educação.

Sim, temos este problema algumas vezes, mas não me parece o caso na [pergunta relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/61200/api-de-pagamentos).

Os usuários do Stack Overflow costumam ser diretos. Por exemplo, o Cigano escreveu:

> A melhor não sei, mas atualizei a tag de pagamento online com uma lista de Gateways. A pergunta não cabe no escopo do site, então esse tipo de informação vai no Wiki da Tag.

Veja, ele se deu ao trabalho de atualizar a informação para ser consultada no local adequado e instruir sobre o uso do site. Não há falta de educação alguma, apenas informação útil, ele está efetivamente ajudando o Autor da Pergunta (AP) e ensinando sobre o uso do site.

Entretanto, pode ser que se espere algo mais polido, por exemplo:

> Olá, senhor, desculpe o incômodo, mas gostaria de lhe informar que não acredito que este seja o local mais adequado para a pergunta, caso concorde com isso, é claro.

Bem, isto para a maioria dos usuários aqui é enrolação e torna a leitura mais difícil e massante.

## Benchmark? API?

O problema da sua [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/61200/api-de-pagamentos), assim como da outra intitulada *[Melhor Servidor Linux](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/61357/3117)* não é a comparação ou escolha de APIs e sim que não se trata de programação ou tecnologia.

Veja, o tema é mais relacionado a comércio, aquisição ou contabilidade do que com programação. A pergunta pede qual método de pagamento é mais vantajoso, então pouco importa a API (interface de programação).

**Escolher um fornecedor não é o mesmo que escolher uma tecnologia.**

Em ambos os casos, é **definitivamente impossível** determinar qual a melhor opção, pois cada usuário possui uma experiência diferente, pode ter tido problemas com um dos fornecedores. No caso de APIs de pagamento, as vantagens variam muito do acordo com a empresa, do volume de vendas, da natureza dos produtos, do público alvo, etc., etc., etc.

Cada usuário do site pode ter uma opinião particular e que não serviria como regra para os demais. Muitos aqui podem até ter contribuições relevantes para a *discussão*, porém o formato do site de Perguntas e Respostas (Q&A) não é adequado para este tipo de debate.

Comment: Desculpa, mas discordo! Quando você fecha uma pergunta, indiretamente você diz que a pergunta é irrelevante, não importa o que o usuário tenha feito antes de fechar a pergunta. Tanto que a mesma pergunta feita por mim novamente não foi fechada, apenas mudando algumas palavras. Apenas retirando a palavra melhor. Parece que alguns usuários procuram perguntas que aparentemente possam ser fechadas, e simplesmente a fecham, sem tentar compreender o que está sendo perguntado.

Comment: Você mesmo se equivocou, supondo que a minha pergunta não é técnica, mas as APIs citadas não suportam o modo de operação descrito.

Comment: @Victor Você está com a impressão incorreta. Pergunta **suspensa** pode significar várias coisas: não está clara, é ampla, **não é um assunto pertinente ao site** (**off-topic**). Realmente temos o problema de usuários que fecham perguntas sem pensar muito e isso ocorre principalmente com perguntas que são ou parecem ser baseadas em opiniões ou são mal formuladas. Muitas delas são trazidas para o meta e, após alguma discussão e da atenção da comunidade e da moderação, as mesmas são reabertas ou não.

Comment: repito, escolha de API sempre é uma escolha de tecnologia. E você mesmo se contradiz quando usa a escolha de palavras **definitivamente impossível**.

Comment: @Victor O fato de incluir API como um sinônimo para sistema ou serviço de pagamento não faz com que isto automaticamente seja relacionado à programação. Dúvida sobre API envolve algo como chamar métodos, passar parâmetros e recuperar valores de serviços REST, SOAP, RPC, DLL, bibliotecas, etc. Dúvidas sobre qual é o contrato mais vantajoso com o serviço de pagamento é um problema financeiro e não tecnológico.

Comment: Seguindo o sentido de **serviço = API*, então eu poderia fazer uma pergunta assim: "pessoal, estou comprando alguns itens através da API do eBay, qual vendedor vocês acham que é mais confiável?" Ou seja, a pergunta em si não tem nada a ver com a API e sim com a *escolha de compra*.

Comment: @Victor A sua segunda pergunta funcionou melhor no site porque ela expressa melhor o seu problema. Você não conhece nenhuma API que faça o que você quer, então o problema real é encontrar *pelo menos uma* que faça (e como eu comentei lá, o próprio pagseguro já da conta do recado). Perguntar assim deixa as coisas mais claras para quem quer responder. Na sua primeira formulação, [você quer uma coisa, mas pede outra](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499). Sem dar critérios sobre o uso das APIs, para além da existência de um determinado recurso, a primeira pergunta não tem resposta objetiva.